# css rules to reorder paragraph text

Tags: html, css

I understand that recent additions to CSS give the style sheet some control to rearrange the appearance of blocks, compared to their ordering in HTML source.

I am wondering whether similar control is available for text within a paragraph.

For example, suppose I have a sequence of `<span>` elements containing text:

```
<p>
<span class="s3">This is the third sentence.</span> 
<span class="s1">This is the first sentence.</span>
<span class="s2">This is the second sentence.</span>
</p>
```

This sequence will display in the browser as a paragraph of three sentences, which flow as continuous text, not formatted blocks.  As seen, however, the order suggested by the contents of the text is not the actual order of appearance.  Is any combination of CSS rules available, selecting on the distinct class names, that would change the order, but still preserve the flow as a single paragraph, as follows?:

> This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence. This is the third sentence.

Solutions should create display results equivalent to that from the following source:

```
<p>This is the first sentence. 
This is the second sentence. 
This is the third sentence.</p>
```

Solutions that would not be helpful are ones that create tabulation or prevent the words from flowing as a normal paragraph.

Also note I am looking only for solutions that are static and portable, not ones that use JavaScript or browser-specific extensions.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** The following answer has an obvious caveat (which you've pointed out): the children remain adjacent to one-another if the window's width drops below a certain threshold.

That in mind, I'm fairly confident that there is really no way for the re-ordered text to wrap naturally. I've added `flex-wrap: wrap` to get slightly closer, although that will still only force the entire child to the next line as opposed to breaking mid-text.

---

Making the parent `<p>` a flex item would allow you to specify the `order` property of its children.

```css
p { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
p > span { white-space: pre; }
p > span::after { content: " "; }
.s1 { order: 1; }
.s2 { order: 2; }
.s3 { order: 3; }
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="s3">This is the third sentence.</span>
  <span class="s1">This is the first sentence.</span>
  <span class="s2">This is the second sentence.</span>
</p>

<p>This is the first sentence. 
   This is the second sentence. 
   This is the third sentence.</p>
```

For more, check out [MDN: Ordering Flex Items - The `order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property).

Comment: Response does not address question.  See note.

Comment: @epl Is the issue the missing spaces between the sentences...? I've added CSS to address this, though I'm not sure why I'm being forced to guess what's wrong here.

Comment: No, the characterization was not determined by the missing spaces, which are easily resolved as you have showed, but rather by the entire text showing on one line, rather than wrapping.  Have you tested with the window width small enough to make the box width smaller than the width of the unwrapped text?  Would you like a capture of my display when I shrink the window as such?

Comment: Again, not sure why the first mention of "small window size" came like pulling teeth. That said, I can tell you with a very high level of confidence that what you're requesting is simply not possible.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I got three responses very quickly, which all separated each sentence into separate blocks.  I didn't want to continue receiving further similar responses. Also, in StackOverflow a question loses attention fast, so if it sits still for too long after receiving a few answers, it rarely gets any more, even if the answers are not helpful to the original questioner.  Instead of commenting individually to each response, I quickly added a note to the post that I thought would clarify for everyone. Would there have been a clearer way to phrase the question?

Comment: @epl The question was well-phrased and clear, I just think that it may have been a bit more efficient to provide the issues with each answer directly instead of a "this isn't what I asked for"-esque blanket. Keep in mind that we're trying to help you out, and sometimes that means helping us out as well! In any case, I've edited my answer to address your concerns. Have a good night.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way seems to be to apply `float:left` the `s1` and `s2` classes:

```css
.s1, .s2 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="s3">This is the third sentence.</span>
  <span class="s1">This is the first sentence.</span>
  <span class="s2">This is the second sentence.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Response does not address question.  See note.

Comment: @epl In which way does this "not address the question"?

Comment: Mostly because it makes each sentence into a non-wrapping block, rather than wrapping the entire paragraph at the natural breaks.